# How can I see what FactoryGirl is outputting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl in my rspec2 test with rails 3.2.1 and I would like to see the FactoryGirl output especially when the test fails.

Is there a way with $stderror puts to get to view what FactoryGirl has created?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Rails logger to write directly to your `log/test.log` file.

I usually add the following to `spec_helper.rb`

```
def logger
  Rails::logger
end
```

now you can log anywhere in your spec like so:

```
describe Customer do

  it "logs factory girl generated objects" do
    customer = Factory( :customer )
    logger.warn( customer.pretty_inspect )
  end

end
```

This will print the generated `customer` object with all properties

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang ... is there a specific place in spec_helper where I need to add 'def logger'?

Comment: Simply add the `def logger` at the end of spec_helper